# Using Lua to retrieve an HTML, split it in to an array by each line, then remove some extra things

Tags: string, lua, split

So I need a function that takes a single parameter, an ID of sorts.

This ID will be added to the end of this incomplete URL: steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=

Then I need the function to retrieve the code of that HTML (plus the ID) and split it in to an array containing each line separately.

Some of those lines are important, every line I need goes like this:

[I put it in paste bin, it wouldn't show up here](http://pastebin.com/GHQa76CZ)

So how should I go about doing this?

A code to fetch the page and assign it to a string, a for loop to check each line of the string and place the 'important' lines in an array, then another for loop to remove everything but the 9 digit code?

Could somebody show me how one could retrieve the HTML by Lua? And how to remove the unimportant parts of the strings?
Any help is appritiated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work; you'll need to install [luasocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html) and replace `google.com` with whatever URL you need:

```
local http = require("socket.http")
local body, code = http.request("http://www.google.com/")
if not body then error(code) end
if code ~= 200 then error(body) end
for digits in body:gmatch('filedetails/\?id="(%d+)"') do
  print(digits)
end
```